# How do I make sure my application only processes 1 message at a time?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a spring-integration application, which uses a message-driven-channel-adapter to receive a xml message from a Websphere MQ queue and then passing this message to a spring integration channel (comprised ) for storing into database.

How do I make sure only 1 message is processed at a time, that is no message can be processed if the preceding message has not reached a specific endpoint (in my case, a service-activator) ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any queue or executor channels, and you leave the default adapter concurrency to 1, the entire flow will run on the single container thread.

Hence, only one message will be processed at a time.

Comment: Well the destination for the message-driven-channel-adapter is an MQQueue, does that mean that what I want can't be achieved ?

Comment: No; I mean no `QueueChannel` or `ExecutorChannel`s in the flow **between** the adapter and your outbound components. These channels hand off the work to another thread. As long as you use the default channel (and don't add an executor to the publish-subscribe channel) both legs will run on the same thread to completion. And, only then, will the next message be processed.